# instant search not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

The code below was for instant search, such as google search.

Note that I didn't include the connect to database function here. Coz I think the database username and password setting would be different to yours.So please create your own if you want to test it. The mysql is set with a table is called "objects", and it has one column named "name".

whenever I type in anything, another new search box pop up, where I was expecting the search result.

Could anyone help PLEASE! I stuck on this for almost a day and need it working by tomorrow.. Thanks in advance!!

```
<!-- display the search area -->
<html>
<!-- google API reference -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- my own script for search function -->

<center>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="search" style="width:400px " placeholder="Search box" onkeydown="searchq();">
    <input type="submit" value=">>">
    <div id="output">
    </div>
</form>
</center>
</html>

<?php
$output="";
if(isset($_POST["searchVal"])){
    //get the search
    $search=$_POST["searchVal"];
    //sort the search
    $search=preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$search);
    //query the search
    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * from objects WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'") or die("could not search!");
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($query);
    //sort the result
    if($count==0){
        $output="there was no search result";
    }
    else{
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

            $object_name=$row["name"];

            $output.="<div>".$object_name."</div>";
        }
    }
}


?>
  <!-- instant search function -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
function searchq(){
    // get the value
    var searchTxt = $("input[name='search']").val();
    // post the value
    $.post("search.php",{searchVal: searchTxt},function(output){
        $("#output").html(output);
    });
}

</script>
```

Comment: You don't need jquery for such a simple task. You can do it in pure javascript in minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `onkeydown` event to `onkeyup` event because `onkeydown` event will not capture current key which is pressed in search result. I have modified your code as below which is working. Please try:

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<!-- google API reference -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- my own script for search function -->

<center>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="search" style="width:400px " placeholder="Search box" onkeyup="searchq();">
    <input type="submit" value=">>">
    <div id="output">
    </div>
</form>
</center>   

  <!-- instant search function -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
function searchq(){
    // get the value
    var searchTxt = $("input[name='search']").val();
    // post the value
    if(searchTxt != "")
    {
        $.post("search.php",{searchVal: searchTxt},function(output){
            $("#output").html(output);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $("#output").html("");
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

PHP file (search.php)

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
$output="";
if(isset($_POST["searchVal"])){
    //get the search
    $search=$_POST["searchVal"];
    //sort the search
    $search=preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$search);
    //query the search
    echo "<br/>SELECT * from objects WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'<br/>";
    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * from objects WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'") or die("could not search!");
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($query);
    //sort the result
    if($count==0){
        $output="there was no search result";
    }
    else{
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

            $object_name=$row["name"];

            $output.="<div>".$object_name."</div>";
        }
    }
    echo $output;
}
?>
```

I am printing what is passed to search.php and query fired in db for debug purpose. Please let me know if any further help required.

Comment: I have modified `searchq()` function which will check whether search box is empty or not. and if it is empty, it'll blank the results. Please check and let me know if any further help required.

Comment: First, thanks!  How to limit the search result to, say, 10?

Comment: To limit search result to 10, you need to modify `SELECT` query as below:
`SELECT * from objects WHERE name LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT 10`

Please check and let me know if any further help required.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks!! I need two more functions on this.. I know I might be a bit greedy..Thanks..I really have no clue about the javascript. First, I used anchor tags on each search result. Q1: But how to direct me to the first search result if enter key is pressed, just like the user have clicked on the first search result?   Q2:  I modify the javascript code as if(txt){ $.post("search.php", {searchVal: txt}, function(result){
           $("#search_output").html(result+"<br><a href='create_object.php'>Not found above? Create.<a>");  });  }     but how to post the searchTxt to the create_object.php ?